# MOSFET Power Supply Explained

Tags: power-supply, transistors, diagram

[image: Circuit Diagram for a MOSFET power supply]

I am struggling to understand how the jumpers at the bottom of this diagram change the voltage of the circuit in this diagram.  The input J1 is a 9V wall wart.

By my understating the MOSFET only amplifies current, not voltage, so how is the output changing with the jumpers?

Edit: I understand now that the transistors are working as an amplifier to give a negative voltage potential to the FET. I am now struggling to grasp how the current changing from the FET changes the output voltage.

Comment: R3 and R7 (and R6 or R5) form a voltage divider.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Probably needs the entire circuit explained.  Few people wouldn't understand the idea of a voltage divider from two resistors. And if they don't, there's no point explaining anything about this.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I understand that there is a voltage divider being created by the resistors, but I don't understand how it is influencing the output.

Comment: @AlecMatthews \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ and \$R_4\$ form a long-tailed pair. It's a basic differential amplifier. Are you familiar with how they work?

Comment: @jonk I am not familiar with them. I am doing some reading now.

Comment: It may help you to assume that there is a significant load resistance on the output. If you keep in mind that current equals  voltage over resistance, this should make it clear that changing the current through a FET can change the output voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feedback circuit:

The voltage divider formed by R3 and R7 (with R6 and R5 potentially in parallel) samples the output voltage and provides the scaled voltage to the base of Q2.

The differential pair formed by Q1 and Q2 is an amplifier that compares the sampled voltage at the base of Q2 with a reference voltage on the base of Q1 (1.2V).

If there is any difference between the two, the gain of the circuit will drive the gate of the FET in such a way as to reduce the difference such that it's close to zero.  So the base of Q2 = base of Q1 = 1.2V.

Therefore the output voltage is approximately 1.2V + R3*1.2V/R7  (or replace the value of R7 with R7 in parallel with whichever resistors are jumpered in to get the other voltage options).

This is essentially a discrete linear regulator.

Comment: So the FET is a voltage amplifier?

Comment: @AlecMatthews You misunderstand. The MOSFET is not amplifying voltage or current. It is regulating the output voltage to be constant under various loads. Z1 is the voltage reference and Q1 and Q2 compare Z1 with the voltage set by the divider R3 and R7. A MOSFET is used due to its low ON resistance. Q2 needs a source of current to work correctly, so its collector is connected to the input voltage.

Comment: @AlecMatthews You could look at the FET in this case as a variable resistor whose resistance is automatically adjusted to drop enough voltage across it to maintain the output voltage at the regulation set point.  Also your statement that a "MOSFET only amplifies current, not voltage" is incorrect, depending on the topology a MOSFET can amplify voltage or current.

Comment: @JohnD That makes a lot more sense. Just to confirm the voltage is adjusted by the drop across the FET, wouldn't that dissipate a lot of heat?

Comment: @AlecMatthews That's one of the disadvantages of a linear regulator.  If the Vin to Vout differential is large and the current is large it can dissipate a lot of heat.  A switching regulator is typically much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgMqK2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your R3 senses the output voltage ( we call it feedback R, Rf) with optional divider R's for different voltage ratios.

The Diff Amp adjusts output bias to ensure input voltages are matched or virtual null input with high open loop gain.

Your Rf=R3=3.3k  and Rin=2k this Vout=1.2V*(1 + 3.3/2) = 3.2V with tolerances